# How to execute nested Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am troubleshooting a slider problem at the moment, however, I don't know javascript that well, I have isolated the .js file that is responsible for the slider functioning, there is a destroy function that I would like to fire off, the code looks like this

```
(function ($) {

$.pixelentity = $.pixelentity || {version: '1.0.0'};

$.pixelentity.peBackgroundSlider = {    
    conf: {
        api: false,
        wait: false
    },
    paused: false
};

function PeBackgroundSlider(target, conf) {

    ...

    function destroy() {
        prevColor = currentColor = currentBW = jwindow = jthis = undefined;
        target.data("peBackgroundSlider", null);
        target = undefined;
    }
}
```

How would I fire off the destroy function in this scenario?

Comment: It would have to be accessed from within `PeBackgroundSlider()`, due it's private scope in that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't as it is right now.

To call it you must "export" it as follows:

```
function PeBackgroundSlider(target, conf) {

...

function destroy() {
    prevColor = currentColor = currentBW = jwindow = jthis = undefined;
    target.data("peBackgroundSlider", null);
    target = undefined;
  }

  return { "destroy": destroy };
}
```

From the caller:

```
var ret = PeBackgroundSlider();
```

Now you can do:

```
ret.destroy();
```

Or, more concise:

```
  return destroy;
```

And:

```
innerDestroy = PeBackgroundSlider();
```

And finally:

```
innerDestroy();
```